# How to get working hours based on the login and logut from biometric data?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to find a logic to calculate working hours of an employee. Now i have a Biometric output data file which i upload to my MYSQL and insert the data. So it give me the EMP_ID and his LOGIN/LOGOUT entry. So I have managed to find his first login and his last logout for a every single day. but Now i want to calculate the time he has working in office. I mean this could be the Scenario:
A employee logs in at 9 am in morning the suppose he goes out for some personal work at 11:50 and comes back 12:20 So there will be entry for 11:50 logout and 12:20 login.

So i want to calculate what actual time he was in office for a single day?

As i mentioned earlier i have his first login and his last logout which defines when he came to office and when he left.

So how can i calculate his total working hours in office time for each single day?

This is my SQL schema for the biometric's login logout data. [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92c73)

And this is the users table:
[image: users table]

Comment: Taking you scenario - Scenario: A employee logs in at 9 am in morning the suppose he goes out for some personal work at 11:50 and comes back 12:20 So there will be entry for 11:50 logout and 12:20 login.  Do you have the 4 times (2 for entry and 2 for exit) recorded your table? If so what are the tables and fields for this. If not, it is not feasible to deduce the actual time that an employee was in the office.

Comment: In my table i have a filed called entry in which if the entry is above 100 we call it login or else its a logout.

Comment: So by that means i can fetch all the records whose entry is below 100 and get all the logouts but the emplyoee and all entry above 100 and get the logins

Comment: But How can i add the time he was in office for suppose he came in at 9 and worked till 12 then goes out and comes back again at 1 so the time i want to calculate will be 10 to 12 as his working then 12 to 1 as his break and then so on he may start to work again and take a break again

Comment: So i want to get his time in office

Comment: Can you post some sample data, how it is been saved in MySQL DB

Answer (score 0):

Create tables with flag (IN/OUT):

```
CREATE TABLE `daily_data2` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `emp_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `entry_time` timestamp,
  `entry_type` tinyint -- Use 1 for in and 0 for out
)
```

Now you can calculate your daily attendance of particular employee.